# Adding zero padding to file name with bash

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a directory full of folders named, e.g., "Week1", "Week2", ..., "Week9", and now I have come to the point where I need a Week10. Having not anticipated this problem beforehand, I now need to rename all of my directories to be "Week01", "Week02", ..., "Week09".

Normally I would do this by hand but I know enough about the MacOS bash terminal to know that I should be able to accomplish this with something like

```
for f = Week[1-9]; do
   mv $f something something
done
```

But I don't know what to put in the "something something" to change the names how I want. How can I insert the zeros into my file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`printf(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1p.html)!

```
for OLD in {1..9}
do
    NEW=$(printf %02d ${OLD})
    mv Week${OLD} Week${NEW}
done
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will accept when I can and read the manual page on printf in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Or like this

```
for D in Week[1-9]; { mv $D ${D//k/k0}; }
```

Comment: I like this also, thank you! I understand this solution a little better.